# keras layer that computes logarithms?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I'd like to set up a Keras layer in which each node simply computes the logarithm of the corresponding node in the preceding layer.  I see from the Keras documentation that there is a "log" function in its backend module.  But somehow I'm not understanding how to use this.

Thanks in advance for any hints you can offer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any backend function inside a `Lambda` layer:

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
import keras.backend as K
```

Define just any function taking the input tensor:

```
def logFunc(x):
   return K.log(x)
```

And create a lambda layer with it:

```py
#add to the model the way you're used to:
model.add(Lambda(logFunc,output_shape=(necessaryWithTheano)))
```

And if the function is already defined, taking only one argument and returning a tensor, you don't need to create your own function, just `Lambda(K.log)`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks!  I've been building my network using the Keras Sequential API, not the Functional API.  How would I do what you're suggesting using the Sequential API?

Comment: it could be actually simplified to `Lambda(K.log)`